# How to take items in a list, and print them to a new .txt document on separate lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

okay, this may have been talked about before, but I am unable to find it anywhere on stack so here i am.

Basically I am writing a script that will take a .txt document and store every other line (even lines say) and print them into a new text document.

I was able to successfully write my code to scan the text and remove the even numbered lines and put them into a list as independent variables but when i got to add each item of the list to the new text documents, depending on where i do that i get either the first line or the last line but never more than one.

here is what i have

```
f = open('stuffs.txt', 'r')
i = 1
x = []
for line in f.readlines():
    if i % 2 == 0:
        x.append(line)
    i += 1
```

I have tested that this successfully takes the proper lines and stores them in list x

i have tried

```
for m in x:
    t = open('stuffs2.txt','w')
    t.write(m)
```

directly after, and it only prints the last line

if i do

```
for line in f.readlines():
    if i % 2 == 0:
        t = open('stuffs2.txt','w') 
        t.write(line)
    i += 1
```

it will print the first line

if i try to add the first solution to the for loop as a nested for loop it will also print the first line. I have no idea why it is not taking each individual item and putting it in the .txt
when i print the list it is in there as it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did look for a canonical - did not find one...

---

`open('stuffs2.txt','w')`  - "w" == kill whats there and open new empty file ...

Read the documentation: [reading-and-writing-files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) :

> **7.2. Reading and Writing Files**
>   `open()` returns a file object, and is most commonly used with two arguments: `open(filename, mode)`. `f = open('workfile', 'w'`)
>
> The first argument is a string containing the filename.
>
> The second argument is another string
>   containing a few characters describing the way in which the file will
>   be used.
>
> `mode` can be **`'r'`** when the file will only be read, **`'w'`** for only
>   writing (**an existing file with the same name will be erased**), and **`'a'`**
>   opens the file for appending; any data written to the file is
>   automatically added to the end. **`'r+'`** opens the file for both reading
>   and writing. The mode argument is optional; `'r'` will be assumed if
>   it’s omitted.

To write every 2nd line more economically:

```
with open("file.txt") as f, open("target.txt","w") as t:
    write = True
    for line in f:
        if write:
            t.write(line)
        write = not write
```

this way you do not need to store all lines in memory.

The `with open(...) as name :`  syntax is also better - it will close your filehandle (which you do not do) even if exceptions arise.

Comment: Thank you for the information, yeah I completely forgot that w will erase everything. haha I was getting so frustrated. In your code, if you do not have a file already created for the ```"target.txt"``` then it will throw an error, to create a new file, i had to put ```open("target.txt","a")```

Comment: @B goodpoint - I added "w" there now - creating  it once should be ok